# Spring Boot design for service with multiple providers(small services)

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, dry, factory-pattern

I am creating a Spring boot application and I need help with the design of my services. 
I will use a bike service as an example. Let's consider these endpoints:

```
/api/bike/v1/info
/api/bike/v1/find
```

The endpoints will call the Bike service, which can potentially call different providers such as  BikeProvider1, BikeProvider2, etc.
The providers will be specified in the properties of the application, this allows to change the provider without restarting the application.

structure example

```
+ bike
     + Client
         - BikeRequest.java
         - BikeResponse.java
     + domain
         - Providers.java //providers enums
         - ServiceType.java // service type enums
        + Exceptions
     + Controller
        - BikeController.java
     + Service
        + Providers
            - BikeProviderService.java //interface
            - BikeProbider1ProviderService.java // implements interface
            - BikeProbider2ProviderService.java // implements interface
        - BikeService.java //interface
        - BikeServiceImpl.java

Properties.file
  bike.provider.primary: BikeProvider1
  bike.provider.fallback: BikeProvider2
```

I also think that in the future I want to have 2 providers one as a fallback in case the first one is not responding. But for now, I will only use the primary.

My current design is this, I have enum classes for my service type and Providers. In the BikeServiceImpl.java I dynamically find the provider that I need and make the call.

```
*******************ENUM CLASSES **************************
public enum Provider {
    BIKEPROVIDER1 ("BikeProvider1"),
    BIKEPROVIDER2  ("BikeProbider2"),

    private String name;

    Provider(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public enum ServiceType {
    BIKEINFORMATION ("BikeInformation"),
    FINDBIKE ("FindBike");

    private String type;

    ServiceType(final String name) {
        this.type = name;
    }
}


*****************BikeProviderService interface**************************

// this is the interface that all providers will implement
public interface BikeProviderService {
    Optional<Bike> getBikeInformation(BikeRequest bike);
    Optional<Bike> findBike(BikeRequest bike);
}

*****************BikeServiceImpl**************************

public class BikeServiceImpl implements BikeService {
    // I autowired providers
    @Autowired
    private BikeProvider1 bikeProvider1;
    @Autowired
    private BikeProvider2 bikeProvider2;

    //Get the provider from the properties
    @Value("${bike.provider.primary:}")
    private String primaryProvider;

// This is the call from controller endpoint /api/bike/v1/info 
    @Override
    public Bike findBikeInformation(BikeRequest bike, ServiceType serviceType) throws ServiceProviderException, BikeNotFoundException {
        return executeBikeInformationWithProvider(primaryProvider, bike, serviceType);
    }

    private Bike executeBikeInformationWithProvider(String provider, BikeRequest bike, ServiceType serviceType) throws ServiceProviderException, BikeNotFoundException {
        // find the providers based on the property value
        Optional<BikeProviderService> bikeProviderService = providerImplementation(provider);

        Optional<Bike> bikeResponse;
        if (BikeProviderService.isPresent()) {
            try {
                bikeResponse = bikeProviderService.get().getBikeInformation(bike);
                if (bikeResponse.isPresent()) {
                    LogCacheService.logRequest(bikeResponse, provider, serviceType.getType());
                    return bikeResponse.get();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new ServiceProviderException("message");
            }
        }

        throw new BikeNotFoundException("Bike Not found");
    }

// This is the call from controller endpoint /api/bike/v1/find 
    @Override
    public Bike findBike(BikeRequest bike, ServiceType serviceType) throws ServiceProviderException, BikeNotFoundException {
        return executeFindBikeWithProvider(primaryProvider, bike, serviceType) ;
    }

    private Bike executeFindBikeWithProvider(String provider, BikeRequest bike, ServiceType serviceType) throws ServiceProviderException, BikeNotFoundException {
       // find the providers based on the property value
        Optional<BikeProviderService> bikeProviderService = providerImplementation(provider);

        Optional<Bike> bikeResponse;
        if (bikeProviderService.isPresent()) {
            try {
                bikeResponse = bikeProviderService.get().findBike(bike);
                if (bikeResponse.isPresent()) {
                    LogCacheService.logRequest(bike, provider, serviceType.getType());
                    return bikeResponse.get();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new ServiceProviderException("message");
            }
        }

        throw new BikeNotFoundException("Bike Not found");
    }

    private Optional<BikeProviderService> providerImplementation(String bikeProvider) {
        Provider provider = null;

        try {
            provider = Provider.valueOf(bikeProvider.toUpperCase());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException ex) {
            log.error("Bike:: invalid Provider {}" , bikeProvider);
        }

        if (provider != null) {
            switch (provider) {
                case BIKEPROVIDER1:
                    return Optional.ofNullable(bikeProvider1);
                case BIKEPROVIDER2:
                    return Optional.ofNullable(bikeProvider2);
                default:
                    return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

I  am trying really hard not to duplicate code, but I afraid I am making this code overcomplicated and super hard to maintain.
adding a new provider right now:

```
1.- add to the enum provider class
2.- add to the switch statement
3.- add the service and @AutoWire the class
```

I tried the factory pattern but I don't want to create a new instance of the provider every time. and is close to the `providerImplementation` method that I have.

Also, I created the execute/helper methods because as I mentioned before, I would like to do a fallback or recover method with the `fallback.Provider` in the future. Example If findBike fails I can call the executeFindBikeWithProvider with the fallback.
`executeFindBikeWithProvider(**fallbackProvider**, bike, serviceType)`

thanks Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a good use case for Spring @Profile?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Instead of using the list of providers in your properties file, you could change your runtime configuration using different profiles. This will effectively allow you to have your providers be ignored or enabled based on your profile setting.

This way, adding a new provider will only require you implementing the new provider and associating it with a profile.

Comment: I see your point, but how can I check which provider is running/enable.? without a big elseif checking every provider .

Comment: What do you mean which provider is running or enabled? Do you just want to know for logging purposes? Or do you want your clients to be able to tell which ones are enabled?